# How to format date and return the value in date format in java

Tags: java

I try to convert my date which is in this format: 
Wed Sep 18 00:00:00 IST 2013 to "18-09-2013 00:00:00" . 
I use

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dd-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss); 

String abc = sdf.format(myDate);// which gives me expected Date format as "18-09-2013 00:00:00"
```

But when i try to convert String to Date again using :

```
Date newDate = sdf.parse(abc); // gives me the default date format as Wed Sep 18 00:00:00 IST 2013
```

What can i do to get result as 18-09-2013 00:00:00 in Date return type

Comment: A date has no format what you see is the internal representation

Comment: A Date object always have the same representation. The only way to format it is to convert it to a String like you already did.

Answer (score 1):

A date as such has no format, but you can use a formatter to generate a formatted version of the date or to parse a string to a date (as you already did). What you can do is to subclass the Date class and to override the toString() method. This way you will see the expected format in case you debug code in your IDE, log the date etc.

```
class MyDate extends Date{
   @Override 
   public String toString(){
       return sdf.format(this)
   }
}
```

Comment: The Main Reason i need to format date into Date format is because Im passing the Date to another method which takes Date as argument and is the generic functionality of my project which cannot be changed

Comment: Ok. But as mentioned in the comments above, if you just pass the date to another method, the formatting is not relevant. Just give it a try and add the exception to your question (in case you get any).

Comment: The date is ultimately passed to a Model class which is mapped to UI thus the format of date is imp